# Problem during wifi driver(rtl8723de) installation in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers

After updating my ubuntu 18.04,I am not seeing wifi option.I guessed that i have to install rtl8723de wifi driver,so i tried using this community question "Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device [10ec:d723]"  (earlier this problem occured many times and problem was solved following the 1st answer ). But this time when i tried this command "
`git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git` terminal output was this

```
koushik@koushik-HP:~$ git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
fatal: destination path 'rtl8723de' already exists and is not an empty directory." 

koushik@koushik-HP:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

And also after doing all the things as in answer 1, my problem is not solved.
Please help me out.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux koushik-HP 5.3.0-59-generic #53~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 4 14:58:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Are you sure you have a `rtl8723de` device?

Comment: yes, Because it is also written  under  my laptop

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: The Jeremy's repo probably is no good for kenel 5.3.

Comment: It is really a `rtl8723de d`. But it was `list`, not `lis`.  Most likely you have problems because you are not accurate with commands.

Comment: i think there sholud not be mistake because i copied and pasted all the commands

Comment: I updated my answer. Remove old clone first and all should work.

Comment: i don't know how to remove old clone.can you guide me

Comment: I did guide you already in my answer.

Comment: You need to delete `rtlwifi_new` directory first. As simple as that.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? If not, it won't work. You can connect using e.g. your phone.

Comment: after deleting, i did this :koushik@koushik-HP:~$ git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
Cloning into 'rtlwifi_new'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

Comment: Connect to the internet first.

Comment: Thank you very much. you were right my internet connection was unstable on that time.My problem is solved now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the driver this way. Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

This will install a driver for new kernels.

If you already cloned, then it may be a wrong branch. So delete it first by

```
rm -rf ~/rtlwifi_new
```

Comment: 3rd command output: koushik@koushik-HP:~$ git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
fatal: destination path 'rtlwifi_new' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have already downloaded that!
You need to change directory to what u have downloaded.

Comment: can you guide me how to do it